# How do I view my XP / level progression?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide

I can see my current player level in one or two locations (e.g. the party menu), but I can't figure out how to view my progression towards the next level.

Is there a way to see my current XP amount compared to the next level, such as "current XP / next XP threshold", or a visual progress bar?

Comment: It's visible when you complete a level, but I'm not sure if you can view it elsewhere.

Comment: @SLC i believe you are correct, sir. I looked everywhere in the menus and the Inn, but I didnt notice the counter at the mission-end screen though. You could post this as an answer if you want, thanks for the tip.